# Find the number of positive integer solutions to $\displaystyle{\displaylines{3x + 2y + z = 2021}}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I was wondering if there is anyway to do the following problem: Find the number of positive integer solutions to $\displaystyle{\displaylines{3x + 2y + z = 2021}}$

As $\displaystyle{\displaylines{2y\in \mathbb{Z}}}$ I have tried to do $\displaystyle{\displaylines{3x + z = 2m - 1}}$ as $\displaystyle{\displaylines{3x + z = 2m - 1}}$ must be odd.

Subsituting $\displaystyle{\displaylines{3x + z = 2m - 1}}$ into $\displaystyle{\displaylines{3x + 2y + z = 2021}}$ ,

$\displaystyle{\displaylines{m + y = 1011}}$

There should be $\displaystyle{\displaylines{1010}}$ pairs of $\displaystyle{\displaylines{(m,y)}}$, excluding the iterations with $\displaystyle{\displaylines{0}}$.

I do not know how to move on from here... Please help me thanks!

Comment: Why did you not take 0+1011=1011 as a pair? 0 is an integer as well

Comment: @Gwen I did not use 0 as an integer as question requires x,y,z to be a positive integer.

Comment: then you should mention it in your question please

Comment: Also then there will be 1009 pairs, as if m=0 then sum of 3x+z = -1 which is not possible if x and z are positive

Comment: Wow I didn't notice that. Then it also should be 1006 pairs? as the minimum of 3x + z is 4!

Comment: It's 5 haha because it's odd. No way it's 4! = 24 XD

Comment: This is the chicken mcnugget problem,  Frobenius coin problem,  or postage stamp problem.  Or maybe it's better to say it's similar,  since one coefficient is $1.$

Comment: In addition to some of the solutions given below, you could also solve this problem using [Pick's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $3x+2y+z=2021$ is a linear Diophantine equation, so we can use available tools to write down all the solutions.

First start with writing $3x+2y = 2021-z$. Since $3$ and $2$ are relatively prime, this has integer solutions for any integer $z$. To obtain all the solutions, we can write $1$ as integer combination of $3$ and $2$ from Euclid's algorithm. I'm joking a bit, that's how you do it in general, but here we clearly have $$1 = 3 - 2 = 3\cdot 1 + 2\cdot (-1)\implies 3(2021-z)+2(z-2021) = 2021 - z$$ which gives us particular solutions for $x$ and $y$, so from [theory of linear Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation), we know that all integer solutions are given by
\begin{align}
x &= 2021-n-2m\\
y &= n-2021+3m\\
z &= n
\end{align}
where $m,n$ are arbitrary integers. It's clear that different choices of $m,n$ will yield different solutions. That combined with the fact that we need only positive integer solutions tells us that the number of desired solutions is equal to the number of integer pairs $(m,n)$ for which the system of inequalities
\begin{align}
0 &< 2021-n-2m\\
0 &< n-2021+3m\\
0 &< n
\end{align}

is true. It's easy to see that this is equivalent to $$2021-3m<n<2021-2m,\ n>0,\tag{1}$$ and this form is suitable for counting.

First observe that $m$ must be positive, otherwise $2021-3m \not < 2021-2m$. Also, $m\leq 1010$ for $2021-2m$ to be positive. We will now split into two cases, when $2021-3m\geq 0$ and $2021-3m<0$.

**1.** $2021-3m\geq 0.$

This happens for $1\leq m \leq 673$ and in that case $(1)$ is equivalent to $2021-3m<n<2021-2m$, so we have  $n\in \{2021-3m+1,2021-3m+2,\ldots, 2021-2m-1\}$, and there are $(2021-2m-1)-(2021-3m) = m-1$ choices for $n$. Total number of choices is then $$\sum_{m=1}^{673}(m-1) = \frac{672\cdot 673}{2} = 226\,128.$$

**2.** $2021-3m< 0.$

This happens for $674\leq m \leq 1010$ and in that case $(1)$ is equivalent to $0<n<2021-2m$, so $n\in \{1,2021-3m+2,\ldots, 2021-2m-1\}$, so there are $2021-2m-1$ choices for $n$. Total number of choices is then \begin{align}\sum_{m=674}^{1010}(2021-2m-1) &= \left[ m = k + 673 \right] = \sum_{k=1}^{337}(674-2k) = 674\cdot 337-2\cdot\frac{337\cdot 338}{2}\\ &= 113\,232.\end{align}

Summing the two cases gives us total of $226\,128+113\,232 = \boxed{339\,360}.$

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way. Since $3x+2y+z=x+(x+y)+(x+y+z)$, the problem is transformed to find how many positive solutions for $a+b+c=2021$ such that $0<a<b<c$.

Without any restriction, there are $2020\choose 2$ positive solutions. Since 2021 is not divisible by 3, it is impossible to have $a=b=c$. Now consider the cases of one equal pair. Let's say $a=b=1$, then $c=2019$ is determined. There are $3\choose 2$ possibilities to choose $a=b$. Hence, we need to exclude ${3\choose 2}\cdot(1010)$ solutions. Now the remaining $ {2020\choose 2}-3030$ solutions satisfy $a\ne b\ne c$. Divide this by $3!$ will be the solution that you want.

Did I make any mistake above?

Comment: A quick triple for-loop verifies the number of solutions to be 339360, which is what you found.

Comment: No mistake, you can remove the question

Comment: Can you explain why the total positive solutions $= ^{2020}C_2$ ? I'm new to combination related theories. I have learnt just the basic in my school. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can put 2021 sticks in a row. There are 2020 spaces between these sticks. Picking any 2 spaces will separate these sticks into 3 parts, which is equivalent to finding one solution to $a+b+c=2021$.

Answer (score 1):

We can give a solution using the ideas (and notation) in the original post:
We have $3x+z=2m-1$, and $m+y=1011$ (for positive integer values of $m$ and $y$).

From positivity requirements we have $1 \le m \le 1010$. For a given value of $m$ in this range, the value of $y$ is completely determined. And then from $3x+z=2m-1$, we can count how many $(x,z)$  pairs correspond to the given value of $m$. We have that $x$ is in the range $1, 2,...,\left\lfloor\frac{2m-2}{3}\right\rfloor$.

So for a given value of $m$ there are $\left\lfloor\frac{2m-2}{3}\right\rfloor$ solutions to the original equation.

Therefore the total number of solutions is given by
$$\sum_{m=1}^{1010} \left\lfloor\frac{2m-2}{3}\right\rfloor $$
We can pair up terms of this expression: $m=k$ and $m=1011-k$
for $k=1,2,...,510$. But each pair of terms adds up to $672$.
To see this, we have

$ \left\lfloor\frac{2k-2}{3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2(1011-k)-2}{3}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{2k-2}{3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2020-2k}{3}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor\frac{2k-2}{3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{1-2k}{3}\right\rfloor +673 = -1+673=672 $

This gives that the total number of solutions of the equation in the original post is $505\cdot 672=339360$

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the correct answer but I got 337 pairs of solutions so please correct me if I made any mistake in any step.

First, take 2y+z = 2k where k is any integer

> I took 2y+z = 2k because as 3x is odd. So we require an even integer to make the sum as odd.

So 3x+2y+z=2021 can be written as 3x+2k=2021

Now the HCF(3,2)=1 and 1 divide 2021 so there are integer solutions to this.

Now we can

List the solutions x0 = 1 and k0 = -1.

So the general solutions to this will be of the form

- x = 2021 + 2t
- k = -2021 - 3t

Here t is any integer.

Also -673>t>-1011

So the value of t will lie between -673 and -1011

So there will be 337 pairs according to me.

Please feel free to point out any mistake in my solution; this is my first answer to the questions on this website. I will try to provide the best and easiest solution to any questions.

Thank you and have a nice day ahead.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input, but we cannot conclude 3x is always odd for all integers x. As for an even x, 3x will always be even. How do we use HCF in this question?

Comment: Pick any $x,y$ from $1$ to $100$, to be modest a while, then $3x+2y$ is less $2021$, adjust with a $z$ so that we have $3x+2y+z=2021$. So far we have some $100^2$ different solutions.